# In spite of ... usage

Tags: phrase-usage

> In spite of their/them arriving late, she was happy.

I wrote this sentence in meaning "Although they arrived late, she was happy."

Is this structure correct? If not, how should I write it properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sentence is correct. 'In spite of' and 'although' are both used to show contrast and mean the same.

'in spite of' (and 'despite') are used before a noun or pronoun:

> In spite of their arriving late
>
> Despite their arriving late

'although' is used before a subject and a verb:

> Although they arrived late